How to use Balser.Pylon.dll as a reference in WinUI 3 code-behind?
I'm currently working on integrating the Basler.Pylon.dll into my WinUI 3 project for camera control. But my project can even not initialize.
I've previously asked a related question, but the error messages had misled me... So, I want to focus on how to correctly reference and use Balser.Pylon.dll, or how to make Basler-related code work in the WinUI 3 code-behind, which is C#.
I found this question, so I tried removing the DLL and adding NuGet Package Basler.Pylon.NET.x64, v8.0.0.10.
The project worked, but the Basler function didn't - CameraFinder.Enumerate() is empty, which means that there aren't any devices that can be connected. The camara can be found via the Basler API, though.
This situation is alike this question, but in C#. Also, in this answer I found out that only using Basler.Pylon.dll as reference should work.
How can I correctly reference and use Basler.Pylon.dll in my WinUI 3 project?

Edit

I found this
question,  so I tried
removing the DLL and adding NuGet Package Basler.Pylon.NET.x64,
v8.0.0.10.
The project worked, but the Basler function didn't -
CameraFinder.Enumerate() is empty, which means that there aren't any
devices that can be connected.

I redo this, and now using the NuGet Package doesn't work, either.

Have you tried just adding an assembly reference?

No... Thanks for your advice, I will give it a try.  I have a question here: When I add Basler.Pylon.dll as reference, there is Basler.Pylon in the Assemblies in my project in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. Is this adding an assembly reference?

Yes. If in doubt, check that the dll is copied to the output folder. Note that you still require the corresponding Pylon SDK version installed on the computer. The dll is not sufficient in itself to connect to any cameras.

Yes, the dll is copied to the output folder. I'm unsure whether the SDK is installed (I didn't find the method to check about it), but my computer can run other Basler WinForm projects.

If you start pylon viewer it should have an about box that lists SDK version.

Thank you, @JonasH. I got my SDK version:
pylon Viewer 64-Bit:
pylon Release 7.4.0.14900,
pylon C++ SDK 7.4.0.38864,
pylon Application 2.1.0.14100,
pylon Viewer 7.4.0.14100. I only saw SDK for c++.
